# Protecting data on the client

Tags: meteor

I was wondering if and how people are preventing data access on the client? Are people concerned with being able to perform insert/update/remove from the JS console with Meteor Apps?

I found this [article](http://andrewscala.com/meteor/) describing how to limit database access on the client but its pretty old and not sure if it is still relevant. They describe this as a way to prevent the client from updating the database:

```
// Relies on underscore.js. In your project directory:
// $ meteor add underscore
Meteor.startup(function() {
    var collections = ['collection_name_1', 'collection_name_2'];

    _.each(collections, function(collection) {
        _.each(['insert', 'update', 'remove'], function(method) {
            Meteor.default_server.method_handlers['/' + collection + '/' + method] =     function() {};
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The Meteor accounts system has been extended since 0.5.0. It provides a `collection.allow` method that allows you to define limitations to access a collection. Check the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#allow).

The `insecure` package on Meteor allows all clients to edit any collection in the database. You need to ensure to `meteor remove insecure` and this will default to deny all clients to write to database.

The [parties](http://www.meteor.com/examples/parties) example screencast talks about this in detail.

Comment: Thanks. I am familiar with Meteor security. Let me rephrase my question. There are certain things that a user can not do because the UI doesnt allow for it (not security restrictions...but workflow restrictions). However from the JS console they can break the workflow. If I wanted this level of control is it best to restrict all database interaction on the client and just use server side meteor methods for database interaction?

Comment: What certain things? Can you give an example?

Comment: For instance, I have a event document that has a field isDeclined. In the UI once the event is declined (ie isDeclined:1) there is not a way for the user to unDecline the event. However in the JS console the user could do something like event.update("6554534d56",{$set:{isDeclined:0}}). So how could I prevent the user from doing this in the JS console? I am using meteor security to only allow a user to insert/update their own event. Is the right thing to add something to meteor security specifically to prevent the change of isDeclined from 1 to 0?

Comment: I add more logic in my collection.allow methods to enforce a specific workflow and report back.

Comment: Meteor gives the freedom to add logic to secure data. You can either entirely leave it insecure or keep it totally secure. But `collection.allow` and `collection.deny` lets you define rules in both cases.

Comment: @shinank Check out [Meteor.methods](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_methods). Use `collection.deny` for updates and call the Meteor method (where collection.update happens) instead of updating the collection directly. A bit delayed. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a similar question recently ([What logic must I cover in Collection.allow and Collection.deny to ensure it's secure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21968840/what-logic-must-i-cover-in-collection-allow-and-collection-deny-to-ensure-its-s))

I find Meteor's allow and deny collections to be woefully insecure. You're right, anyone can just edit the data they have available. And it's up to you to write your Allow function to properly check exactly how a user might manipulate a document.

At some stage, I'm sure Meteor will have built in features like schema checking or whatever to may it easier to do this in the future. Right now, I've concluded the easiest and cleanest thing I've found is to just revoke all server side database permissions on the client side and just do all write operations with Meteor.calls and do my own validations that way